# Несовершенный вид в значении совершенного

Tags: глаголы, история-языка, вид

Мы то и дело используем в прошедшем времени несовершенный вид там, где он по базовому смыслу  вполне заменим на совершенный, однако контекст требует подчеркнуть, что было выполнено некое предписанное или необходимое действие.

Например:

*Номер телефона **вводил**, но никакого подтверждения не пришло.* (Говорящий, скорее всего, ввел номер один раз, а не несколько.)

*"У меня что-то спина уже неделю болит." "К врачу **ходил**?"* (Опять же несовершенный вид подчеркивает предписанность действия, а не его многократность или продолжительность.)

Интересует меня вот что: есть ли исследования на тему того, с каких пор в русском языке отмечается такое употребление? Потому что объяснить его можно двумя разными способами: либо чисто семантическим (некая виртуальная "продолжительность" действия подчеркивает, что важен не столько результат, сколько процесс), либо историческим. Второй интереснее и опасно располагает к спекуляциям, но нельзя не отметить: такая функция у несовершенного вида есть только в прошедшем времени. *Даже если ты **введешь** номер, подтверждения не придет* — "будешь вводить" здесь неуместно.

Поэтому возникает такое предположение: несовершенный вид в этом значении был еще в пору, когда прошедших времен в русском было четыре, и оттенок "предписанности" выражался как раз через выбор глагольного времени. Возможно, это одно из исконных употреблений несовершенного вида в перфекте, который теперь стал нашим единственным прошедшим временем, а в прочих случаях ему предпочитался аорист или имперфект. Или наоборот, там как раз требовался аорист?

Comment: Очевидно, что это означает повторяемость или неопределенное количество раз выполненное действие. "Номер телефона ввёл" - ввёл один раз, намекает, что возможно ввёл ошибочно, "номер телефона вводил" - вводил один или несколько раз, исключает, что ввёл ошибочно. "К врачу ходил?" - ходил ли к одному или нескольким врачам? "К врачу сходил?" - сходил ли к одному, своему врачу? Второе намекает на вопрос, сходил к врачу за справкой или документом, за тем, что у врача можно получить один раз, много раз за справкой не ходят. Первое - имеет в виду визит к врачу(чам) за советом, лечением.

Comment: @NikolayErshov Я не знаю, как в прошлом, а сейчас для несовершённого вида выделяют т.н. *общефактическое* значение, когда интересует не действие как событие привязанное к какому-то моменту в прошлом, а сам факт того, что оно имело место/не имело места. Есть умеренно длинная книга по семантике глагольного вида, где показывается (на мой взгляд, достаточно убедительно), как все частные значения несовершённого вида выводятся из *актуально-длительного*, которое считается прототипичным.

Comment: Наверное, здесь вернее спросить, как складывалась вообще видовая система. Но этот ответ будет достоин быть записанным золотыми иглами в уголках глаз.

Comment: «Многократность или продолжительность» не является характеристикой несовершенного вида, это лишь частные случаи. Поскольку совершенный вид означает действие конечное (имеющее начало, «пошёл», либо конец, «пришёл»), то противопоставляемый ему несовершенный вид, «ходил», означает действие неконечное, не имеющее начала или конца, ну или же такое, где его конечность говорящему не важна.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[М.Г. Безяева](http://www.philol.msu.ru/%7Eruslang/about/employee/bezyaeva.m.g/) в книге "Семантика коммуникативного уровня звучащего языка" указывает на различное коммуникативное значение совершенного и несовершенного видов. Другими словами, выбор вида зависит от того, как мы оцениваем ситуацию, а не только от номинативного и грамматического значений глагольного вида.  Безяева даёт следующее определение инвариантному значению видов:

> Форма несовершенного вида - должное, необходимое, нужное (с модификациями алгоритма развёртывания).
>
> Форма совершенного вида - возможность, способность (с модификациями алгоритма развёртывания).

(Безяева М.Г,Семантика коммуникативного уровня звучащего языка, Москва, Издательство Московского университета, 2002 - с. 721)

В вашем примере несовершенный вид глагола "вводил" как раз подчёркивает необходимость совершения действия, то есть посыл говорящего здесь "я сделал всё, что должен был, всё, что было обязательно и необходимо".

Коммуникативная семантика является относительно новым направлением в лингвистике, но мне данное объяснение кажется убедительным.

Comment: Хорошо, другой пример: _«приходил посетитель, я ему подписала все, что он хотел»_ .
Тут три глагола, все три действия по смыслу уже завершенные, однократные, примерно одинаковой степени необходимости. 
Как можно объяснить по формальным признакам, почему «подписала» в совершенном виде, а остальные два нет?

Comment: Я могу только честно сказать - я не знаю, почему.
Коммуникативное значение сосуществует с номинативным, дополняя его.

Comment: Очень интересный взгляд на русскую видовую систему изложил Yukihide Hashimoto в книге "Effective Learning OF the Russian Verbal Aspect". Господин Хашимото овладел русским языком и поделился своим опытом понимания глагольных видов. Он пишет, что для совершенного вида характерно представление действия  как "ограниченного", имеющего внутренние временные пределы, а несовершенный вид таких пределов не имеет. Приходил - не определены рамки действия, хотел - тоже.

Comment: As I understand your sentence @J-mster, and as I learned in college, the first verb приходил happened "somewhere in time", not connected to another event, and is used to introduce a time frame. Подписала, on the other hand, is defined in time by приходила, so here we see the рамки действия Eugenia Vlasova talks about (one action, completed). The third verb хотел does not really have a perfective counterpart here (захотел? no), because it would change the meaning. Reference: Barentsen 1995: Semantika i struktura slavjanskogo glagol'nogo vida 1, 1-26.

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference in the meaning.

> К врачу ходил?

Have you visited a/the doctor one or more times due to your condition (for advise, treatment, extended diagnostics, anything one can do several times)?

> К врачу сходил?

Have you visited a/the doctor due to your condition (for a document, certificate, certain one-time test, anything non-repeatable)?